# Is there a way to replace only the first zero in a column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

So I have a data frame that looks like

| df |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |

Is there a way to change just the first zero, the one in row 7, to a different value I have stored in my environment. In this exact case it's the value is stored under

```
new <- .4
```

The first 0 is in a different place for each dataset I have, some are dozens of rows long.

Comment: I should add, the first 0 is in a different place for each dataset I have, some are dozens of rows long.

Answer (score 0):

There should be multiple ways to do this.

Here is an option with `match` -

```
data <- data.frame(num = rep(c(1, 0), c(6, 3)))
new <- .4
data$num[match(0, data$num)] <- new
data

#  num
#1 1.0
#2 1.0
#3 1.0
#4 1.0
#5 1.0
#6 1.0
#7 0.4
#8 0.0
#9 0.0
```

`match` would return index of 1st matching value.

Answer (score -1):

For replacing a single value at a specific location you can use

```
df[<Row number>, <Column number>] <- <New value>
```

In your case that would be:

```
df[7, 1] <- .4
```

or for the stored variable `new`:

```
df[7, 1] <- new
```